# two tex files in same table

Tags: tables

I want to include a large regression output contained in a tex file generated in **Stata**.
I decided to generate two files (one with the first 15 variables and the second with the other fifteen)
I then use

```
\input(firstfile.tex}
\input(secondfile.tex}
```

But in the document I get two tables called table 1 and table 2 and I want them to be called "Table 1 (first part)" and "Table 1 (second part)", respectively. Is that possible?
Thank you very my much
Juan

Comment: Welcome! It most likely is possible, perhaps with the `catchfile` package, but one needs definitely more concrete information. Can you please post a minimal document and toy versions of the two table files so that others can use those for their answer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the second input so that you can modify the table counter and modify the caption in this way:

```
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\caption{(continued) Foo ...}
```

I cannot guess if the tables will be in the same or different `table` floats, but that is irrelevant for the above, so the final result must be equivalent to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Foo}   
\begin{tabular}{ll} 11 & 12 \\21 & 22\\ \end{tabular}

\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\caption{(continued) Bah}   

\begin{tabular}{ll} 31 & 32\\   41 & 42\\ \end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```